# Forming & enforcing placement of equations as well as text box

Tags: floats, equations, positioning, align, ieeetran

I want to have the set of equations in the TeX code below and a text box to be placed alike the picture below. Can someone kindly provide me a solution? It is IEEE two-column page style.

[image: Make Alike]

This is my set of equations:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx, lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!t]
%\begin{equation}
\[\mathop {\min }\limits_{R_t} \,\,\,\,\,\,F_t^o = \mathop \sum \limits_{k = 
1}^n \mathop \sum \limits_{j = 1}^m \left( {{w_1}{F_{\Delta {T_{kj}}}} + 
{w_2}{F_{\Delta {V_{kj}}}}}   \right)\]

\[\begin{array}{l}
s.t.\,\, \to \,\,\,x_n^c(\kappa ) \in {\mathbb{Z}} \cap \left[ {{x_{in1}}
(\kappa ) \le x_n^c(\kappa ) \le {x_{in2}}(\kappa )} \right]\,\,\,\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall i \in {\mathbb{R}^+}\,,\,\,c = \{ 
1,2,...,20\} \\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall n \in {\mathbb{R}^+}\,,\,\,n = \{ 
1,2,...,20\} \\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall \kappa  \in {\mathbb{R}^+}\,,\,\kappa  
= \{ 1,2,3,4\}    \hfill (1)
\end{array}\]


\[{F_{\Delta L}} = \mathop \sum \limits_{t = {t_0}}^{\frac{{{t_2} - {t_0}}}
{{\Delta t}}} {\left( {\Delta F\left( t \right) - 20} \right)^2} \times 
\left( {\left| X \right| \times \left( {t - {t_0}} \right) \times \Delta L} 
\right)\] \hfill{(2)}

\[{F_{\Delta L}} = \mathop \sum \limits_{t = {t_0}}^{\frac{{{t_2} - {t_0}}}
{{\Delta t}}} {\left( {\Delta F\left( t \right) - 20} \right)^2} \times 
\left( {\left| X \right| \times \left( {t - {t_0}} \right) \times \Delta L} 
\right)\] \hfill{(3)}


\[{x_{lolep}}(\kappa ) = \mathop {arg\min }\limits_{x_n^i} \,\left[ 
{F_X^o(t),\,\,x_n^o(\kappa ) \in \left[ {{x_{in2}}(\kappa ),{x_{in3}}(\kappa 
)} \right]} \right]\]  \hfill (4)

\[\begin{array}{l}
x_n^0 = \left\{ {\forall \kappa  \in {\mathbb{R}^+}\,,\,\,\kappa  = 
[1,9]\,\,|\,\,\,x_n^0(\kappa ) \in{\mathbb{Z}}  \subseteq \left[ {{x_{in1}}
(\kappa ),{x_{in2}}(\kappa )} \right]\,\,} \right\}\,\\ \vspace{5cm}
\,\,\,\,\,\, = \left[ {x_n^0(1)\,...\,x_n^0(9)} \right] = \left[ {k_{p1 
10}^i,\,T_{1 10}^i,\,k_{p2 11}^i,\,T_{2 11}^i} \right]
\end{array}\] %\hfill (5) \\
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}%\vskip3pt
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You might want to look up the command `\quad` instead of al those `\, `, learn to make argmin,

Comment: @daleif: Don't worry, "that is not the concern". I have written Eqs in MathType and transferred to LateX. that is why it looks like that. This code works perfectly and no problem. Question is how to make it look like the one in the picture?!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

but for this was necessary to rewrite all equations ...

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}%[conference]{IEEEtran}
%\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
%\ifCLASSINFOpdf
%\else
%\fi

\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
    \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\;min}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{url}

 \usepackage{enumitem}       % new
 \usepackage{lipsum}% for text demo

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{figure*}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}\vspace{-3ex}
\begin{align}
\min_{R_t} F_t^o
    & = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \left(w_1 F_{\Delta {T_{kj}} +
{w_2}{F_{\Delta {V_{kj}}}}}   \right)                       \\
\begin{split}
s.t. \to
    & x_n^c(\kappa ) \in {\mathbb{Z}} \cap
        \left[x_{in1} (\kappa) \le x_n^c(\kappa) \le {x_{in2}}(\kappa) \right]\\
    & \forall i \in \mathbb{R}^{+},\quad c = \{1,2,...,20\} \\
    & \forall n \in \mathbb{R}^{+},\quad n = \{1,2,...,20\} \\
    & \forall \kappa  \in {\mathbb{R}^+}\,\quad \kappa = \{ 1,2,3,4\}   (1)
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.40\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=(\roman*)]
\item   \dots\dots\dots
\item   \dots\dots\dots
\item   \dots\dots\dots
\item   \dots\dots\dots
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
\begin{align}
F_{\Delta L}
    & = \sum_{t=t_{0}}^{\frac{t_{2} - }t_{0}
                             {\Delta t}}
        \left(\Delta F(t) - 20\right)^{2} \times
    \left(\lvert X \rvert \times \left(t - t_{0} \right) \times \Delta L\right)  \\
F_{\Delta L}
    & = \sum_{t = t_{0}}^{\frac{t_{2} - t_{0}}
                               {\Delta t}}
        \left(\Delta F(t) - 20 \right)^{2} \times
        \left(\lvert X \rvert| \times (t - t_{0}) \times \Delta L \right)
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.40\linewidth}\vspace{2.2ex}
\begin{flalign}
\begin{split}
x_{\text{lolep}}(\kappa )
   &  = \argmin_{x_n^i} \Bigl[F_X^o(t), \\  
   &\quad     
        n^o(\kappa) \in \left[x_{in2}(\kappa),
        x_{in3}(\kappa)\right]\Bigr]
\end{split}                                             &   \\  
x_n^0
    & = \Bigl\{\forall  \kappa \in \mathbb{R}^{+},
        \kappa = [1,9]                                  &   \\
x_n^0 (\kappa)
    & \in \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \bigl[x_{in1}(\kappa),
        x_{in2}(\kappa)
                \bigr]\Bigr\}\,                         &   \\ 
    & = \left[x_n^0(1)\dots x_n^0(9) \right]            &   \\
    & = \left[k_{p110}^i, ,T_{110}^i,\  
                    k_{p211}^i, T_{211}^i \right]       &
\end{flalign}
\end{minipage}
\rule[-1ex]{\textwidth}{.5pt}%\vskip3pt
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. (1) I need the indentation of equations on the right-side column aligned with the text box vertical border and more like the one I showed there. (2) Inside text box writing alike shown. (3) variable exactly centered beneath argmin. (4) The two equations on the right remaining at the same line alike shown. Appreciate if you could help with this.

Comment: @Hans, see edited answer.

Comment: Regarding (1) and (4) a quick fix can be using \hspace ! isn't there another way

Comment: @Hans, please don't make this question newer-end-story :). in your comment below question you claim, that equation as they are, work fine for you ... please about formatting of equations ask new question that more people can see your new problem and will be able eventually to help you. some sketch (for example based on my answer) about new problem can help a lot. sorry, but i don't understand your last request. where you like to employ `\hspace`? so far i can only say: try and see the result.